# New 2020 Macbook Pro: Headphone jack doesn't work upon logging in, often doesn't work until I plug in/out several times

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a new mabook pro. Everytime I open the laptop and login, the computer doesn't seem to register my headphone jack. On the touch bar there isn't an option to control the volume. I always have to plug the headphone in and out, and then it registers. And sometimes I have to plug it in and out 8-15 times before it works. After the first time, there is an option for volume, but the headphones often still don't work. After around 15 times the headphones finally have sound.

Comment: Classic example of a hardware failure in a headphone jack. Contact Apple for warranty service.

Comment: May be an IO board failure, but check that the sound output is set to headphones when you plug in your headphones. You can check what the output is in sound settings in system preferences